# how to search for the word instead of the whole combination

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    a = ["hi","hel","jhd"]
    b = "hhgghihjh"
    if(any (x in b for x in a)):
         print("found")
```

the above gets True because the word "hi" is found in the the other word.i want it to state False because i just want to check the word instead of checking the desired word in the main word.i am a newbie to python.Thanks

Comment: could you give an example of what you want exactly. Did you mean that there will be multiple words with spaces in between the words?

Comment: Are you looking for full word matching strictly?

Comment: as stated in the code above the code will output "found",but that's what i dont want it to do.It is because the word hi is found in the other word.Python is actually checking the bigger word letter by letter for the word "hi".i want the code to state False as both the words do not match

Comment: yes strict word matching

Answer (score 1):

You can use the == operator for string comparison.

```
a = "hi"
b = "hhgghihjh"
if ("x" == a or "x" == b):
    print("found")
```

Or for searching the string for a specific key, use `in`.

```
a = "hi"
b = "hhgghihjh"
if ("x" in a or "x" in b):
    print("found")
```

Comment: There is nothing like 'strict' and 'non-strict' comparisons. Your first code snippet is a string comparison and second snippet is a substring search.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: a = "hi"

In [12]: b = "hhgghihjh"
```

`==` checks that 2 arguments have the same value.

```
In [14]: 'h' == a or 'h' == b
Out[14]: False
```

Using `a in b` is simply translates to `b.__contains__(a)`, which *should* return if b includes a or not.

```
In [15]: 'h' in a or 'h' in b
Out[15]: True
```

but python is `case-sensitive` language which mean `Uppercase` is different from `Lowercase`

```
In [16]: 'H' in a or 'H' in b
Out[16]: False
```